# import GoogleMobileAds No such module 'GoogleMobileAds '

Tags: swift, xcode, objectify

Hello i have this error help me to solve it

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to Java.

Comment: Try clean and build. Sometimes it sorts itself out.

Answer (score 3):

try doing the following steps:

1. Put the path of `GoogleMobileAds.framework` in Targets -> Build
   Settings "Framework Search Path"
2. Set "No" under Project -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode

Comment: Disabling bitcode was the solution for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you so much you have ended my hours of searching!

Comment: Also step 1 was only necessary for me I still have bitcode enabled